# What are some key difference in functionality between ProM and Apromore?

Tags: data-mining

I would like to know what are some use cases where one would use ProM and where one would use Apromore.

I have traces and events from logs that I would like to use process mining on (mapping a business process from these informations, filter to isolate types of cases, estimating average time for each event, estimating the percentage of cases that go through a branch, visually, etc.), but I have a hard time choosing a tool. Also, the two seem able to interact; therefore, I have trouble understanding the key features of both.

ProM seems to be a more desktop application, while Apromore web-based, distributed via a Docker image, but functionality-wise, what are some differences?

Answer (score 2):

Below are three key differences.

1. Apromore is a server-side collaborative tool. It is typically installed on a server (on-premise or on the cloud). Users connect to Apromore via the Web browser. Users can upload process models and event logs, organize them into folders, enrich them with log filters and dashboard designs, and share them with other users. Apromore comes with a process model editor, so you can edit the process models you discover from your event logs, beautify them, and export them in BPMN format (so you can share them with other tools). Meanwhile, ProM is a desktop tool. You typically install it in your laptop. You use it to analyze an event log locally, but you cannot use it in a collaborative manner with say 3-4 team members. You cannot save your analysis (e.g. custom dashboards, filters) in ProM.
2. A second difference is that Apromore supports BPMN natively. The process discovery algorithm in Apromore is Split Miner, which discovers BPMN models by design. Traditionally, ProM is designed to support an academic notation called Petri nets, which is used in research studies but generally not used by process improvement practitioners.
3. Finally, Apromore supports both process mining use cases (discovery, conformance), but also process performance monitoring use cases via customizable process performance dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

### Key Differences

- I think that first of you have to look at the authors of both software tools. 
  *Apromore* was designed and developed at the University of Melbourne, whereas *ProM* was born at the Technical University of Eindhoven (TUe). TUe was till recently the university where Prof. Wil van der Aalst, the so called father of process mining, had his chair.
- Second of, the architecture of the two applications differs. Whereas *Apromore* is a self-contained tool, with all the algorithms coming pre-packaged with it, *ProM* is more of a skeleton of an app, with a package manager attached, so you can install whatever package the academia or other authors have newly come up with.

### Recommendations

Depending on your use-case I would personally recommend for you to try out both. Furthermore, I would encourage you to also try other tools such as [Disco](https://fluxicon.com/disco/) from Fluxicon (a start-up composed of two of van der Aalst's former students), to get a better feel for what works for you.

Strictly for analysis and process mining in action I think the latter is a better tool than both. In contrast the former two tools are more appropriate if you are interested to learn hands-on the different algorithms with their advantages and their limitations.

Lastly, if you are a tinkerer I could imagine that a process mining software library for python, such as [PM4Py](https://github.com/pm4py/pm4py-source), would be appropriate for you.